# convert date string coming in two different formats YYYYMMDD and DDMMYYYY to date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Tried the below but it only takes care of one format

```
string date = "20100102";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Please specify why you even **have** data reaching you in YYYYMMDD or DDMMYYYY to begin with. Something must be very wrong in a way earlier part for this to occur. There is no unambigious way to differentiate between those two formats. So you should not have them reacah you like that to begin with.

Comment: @Christopher actually it is a legitimate case.  I once had to parse user-created text files and not everyone used the same date convention. We were all in the same locale too

Comment: @MickyD: As I said, something went wrong before. Like when creating that textfile. You should have made certain that there was one fixed DateTime Format that everyone adhered too when creating the file. Or a CSV file with day/month/year as seperate fields. If you ever get data like "20122011" it becomes impossible to figure out wich of the two styles is implied. That is why you can not reliably imply a format. It has to be known.

Comment: @Christopher these are dates coming from excel uploads, so different files are coming with different date formats.

Comment: @Christopher OP isn't looking for YYYYDDMM format

Comment: @MickyD: His title disagrees. And that is about all we got to work with.

Comment: @Christopher corrected

Comment: @Prince Excell does not actually stores DateTimes in that format. Internally it counts days since day X (wich I think was 1st Janurary of 1960 or so). So what you have here is either: a) A total missinterpretation of the value you got. b) Excel somehow storing the culture the value was typed in under and returning hte properly cultured value.

Comment: @Christopher Or the date column was a text cell.

Comment: @Christopher The example 20122011 is ambiguous only if you think year 2012, __month 20__, day 11 is valid. I think ambiguity _can_ occur if one date may be in the 13th century AD (which is supported by `System.DateTime`). Possible example: `"20111220"` (2011-Dec-20, or 20-Nov-1220).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
 DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

...try:

```
var dateString = "20100102";
var formats = new String[]{"yyyyMMdd", 
               "ddMMyyyy"};
DateTime dateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                    DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                    out dateValue))
    Console.WriteLine ("Success");
```

MSDN has this to say on `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats, culture-specific format information, and style. **The format of the string representation must match at least one of the specified formats exactly**. The method returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

### Tell me more

- *[DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__)*

Comment: The problem is that in reality you might hit a value like "20122011". Both variants of parsing would be valid, but the results would be a literal year appart. You can try guessing like the WebBrowser will guess Encodings, but it will always stay a guess: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @Christopher true, but OP isn't looking for YYYYDDMM.  TryParseExact is designed for when you _don't know_ the exact format ahead of time.  I found it worked perfectly well in a prior project as I mentioned

Comment: @MickyD thanks but it's returning a false for  20180808

Comment: @Prince The correct format is `yyyyMMdd` and `ddMMyyyy`, the `y` and `d` must be in lowercase. I've tried 20180808 and it returns true

Comment: whoops!  thanks for spotting that and for edit @currarpickt :)